# Open url in browser but do not show the url

Tags: android, android-webview

I am creating a shortcut at home screen of device to open an url in browser as

```
public void addBookmarks(MyBookMarks bookMarks) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Creating Bookmarks for " + bookMarks.getUrl()); 
    final Intent intent = new Intent();
    final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
            Uri.parse(bookMarks.getUrl()));
    long urlHash = bookMarks.getUrl().hashCode();
    long uniqueId = (urlHash << 32) | shortcutIntent.hashCode();
    shortcutIntent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, Long.toString(uniqueId));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, bookMarks.getLabel());
    if (bookMarks.getBookMarkIcon() != null) {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, 
                Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bookMarks.getBookMarkIcon(), 128, 128, true));
    } else {
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, "");
    }

    //intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, bookMarks.getBookMarkIcon());
    intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT); 

    this.mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

***Problem***

When I open the shortcut it shows the url into browser, that I want to hide. How can I do this?

Comment: You should use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

Comment: I am creating a shortcut like applications shortcuts.

Comment: Hiding the address bar is mostly impossible, as you cannot control the various Android web browsers. What you need to do is create an activity that displays the page in a `WebView` and you launch that as above.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use WebView in the application

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.webview);
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

 }
```

Comment: I am creating shortcuts of url to home screen.